# Allow domain machine account to access shared folders outside of its domain

Tags: windows, cross-domain

Is there a way to grant a domain machine account (e.g. `DOM1\SPLUNKSERVER$`) access to a shared folder like `\\DOM2\QA_SERVER\LOGS`?

As the sample account and folder imply, I'm trying to give our Splunk server access to a shared folder that sits on a different domain.

Comment: Off-topic here, try Server Fault.  You should probably explicitly state whether the domains are in the same forest or not, and whether they share an explicit trust relationship or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using nfs file share. \Server\Logs  can be mounted and then accessed from the other machine.